# ORACLE - Split string and create cursor

Tags: oracle

I am having a problem with an oracle theme

we have a table where one of its columns stores data separated by comma (,) ex

| id | type | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1234567890,A,asd,12345 |
| 2 | 1 | 8456321790,B,dde,12345 |

we need to be able to separate that value and get as a result something like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | A | asd | 12345 |
| 8456321790 | B | dde | 12345 |

but this amount of column is not fixed some type can be of a different lake of data and we need to respond dynamically to that for example

| id | type | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1234567890,A,asd,12345 |
| 2 | 1 | 8456321790,B,dde,12345 |
| 3 | 2 | 1111155555 |
| 4 | 2 | 7777788888 |

if I run the process for 1 one the result is as before

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | A | asd | 12345 |
| 8456321790 | B | dde | 12345 |

but if I run it for type 2 the result should be as follows

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1111155555 |
| 7777788888 |

we could convert the item field into a table of varchar2 but we couldn't find how to convert it to use it with a cursor.
Any idea?
Thank you very much!
sorry if my english is not understood, it is not my native language.

Comment: Well, that's definitley a bad data model you are having to deal with. Can't you just provide for the maximum number of columns in your query and have the not used ones empty? Example with six columns: **type 1:** col1=1234567890, col2=A, col3=asd, col4=12345, col5=null, col6=null. **type 2:** col1=1111155555, col2=null, col3=null, col4=null, col5=null, col6=null. That would make things easier. Or better still: can you change the data model? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really care which `type` it is? Would this do? (sample data in lines #1 - 6; actual query begins at line #7):

```
SQL> with test (type, item) as
  2    (select 1, '1234567890,A,asd,12345' from dual union all
  3     select 1, '8456321790,B,dde,12345' from dual union all
  4     select 2, '1111155555' from dual union all
  5     select 2, '7777788888' from dual
  6    )
  7  select
  8    regexp_substr(item, '\w+', 1, 1) col1,
  9    regexp_substr(item, '\w+', 1, 2) col2,
 10    regexp_substr(item, '\w+', 1, 3) col3,
 11    regexp_substr(item, '\w+', 1, 4) col4
 12  from test;

COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1234567890 A          asd        12345
8456321790 B          dde        12345
1111155555
7777788888

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CASE operator is coming for your rescue

```
select id, 
       case when type = 1 then substr(item, 1, instr(item, ',')-1) else item end col1,
       case when type = 1 then substr(item, instr(item, ',')+1, instr(item, ',', 1, 2)-instr(item, ',') - 1) end col2,
       case when type = 1 then substr(item, instr(item, ',', 1, 2) + 1, instr(item, ',', 1, 3) - instr(item, ',', 1, 2) - 1) end col3,
       case when type = 1 then substr(item, instr(item, ',', 1, 3) + 1, length(item) - instr(item, ',', 1, 3)) end col4
  from some_table
```